# jruby multithreading const_missing

Tags: ruby, multithreading, jruby

I'm trying to parallelize processing in a JRuby loop (using peach), but crash with the const_missing errors after about 30 seconds of running smoothly:

```
lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:452:in `load_missing_constant'
lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `const_missing_with_dependencies'
lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:118:in `const_missing'
lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:463:in `load_missing_constant'
lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:122:in `const_missing'
```

I'm using jrub 1.5.2:

```
C:\projects\sami\build>jruby -v
jruby 1.5.2 (ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 249) (2010-08-20 1c5e29d) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_11) [amd64-java]
```

And I've set up my environment to enable multithreading:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.threadsafe!
config.dependency_loading = true if $rails_rake_task
```

What else can I do!?

TIA

Comment: 1) does it work when you don't run multiple threads? 2) What's the actual error? you only posted part of the stack trace but not the message which triggered it. What Constant was being referenced that AS::Dependencies was trying to resolve? 3) Why a 2 year old jruby?

Comment: is `$rails_rake_task` truthy in the context of your crash?  If so, your problem is likely that you've partially undone `config.threadsafe!` by setting `config.dependency_loading = true`

Comment: 1) it does work on a single threaded (using 'each' instead of 'peach') 2) The const_missing error shows up in various classes - it is random from run to run 3) Yes, it's old.  And I am running via Rake.  I've tried various environment settings (with/without config.dependency_loading) - nothing works.

Comment: Please post a more complete error output including the error message and the whole stack trace -- the six stack frames you've excerpted are insufficient. Edit your original question to supply the requested info unless it's very short. Can you show us the `#peach` loop too? (When asking for help from strangers, you'll get better luck not being stingy on data and responding to questions faster than a 4 day cycle.)

Comment: Have you tried your code on a more up to date jruby? There are numerous mentions of fixes to various concurrency bugs between 1.5.2 and now.